# Can I use ngx-bootstrap sortable component with formArray?

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable, ngx-bootstrap

When I try to use ngx-bootstrap sortable component with formArray I faced a lot of errors when I tried to mix usage of reactive forms directives and bs-sortable component.

```
<ng-template #imageTemplate let-item="item" let-index="index"><span>{{index}}: <pre>{{item | json}}</pre></span></ng-template>
<bs-sortable
    [(ngModel)]="imagesFormArray.controls"
    [itemTemplate]="imageTemplate"
    itemClass="sortable-item"
    itemActiveClass="sortable-item-active"
    placeholderItem="Drag here"
    placeholderClass="placeholderStyle"
    wrapperClass="sortable-wrapper"
></bs-sortable>
```

The error I get in the console is

```
ERROR Error: 
  ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
  formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.`
```

If I change `ngModel` to `formArrayName` there is no error, but nothing is outputed at all.

The official documentation has only `ngModel` approach, but this doesn't work fro me

Comment: Hi @Basma Ashraf, Can you share what sort of errors are you getting?

Comment: The error you got is nothing with ngx-bootstrap. And yes, you can pass an array.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hlawza-txu77m?file=app%2Fcustom-item-template.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ngx-sortablejs](https://github.com/SortableJS/ngx-sortablejs).
It worked like a charm in my case.